# How to build pgmagick on linux (CentOS)?

Tags: python, centos, graphicsmagick, pgmagick

I'm not having much success when attempting building `pgmagick` on CentOS 5.6.

I've installed the following via `yum`:

```
boost-1.33.1
boost-devel-1.33.1
GraphicsMagick-1.3.14
GraphicsMagick-c++-1.3.14
GraphicsMagick-devel-1.3.14
GraphicsMagick-c++-devel-1.3.14
python-2.6.5
python-devel-2.6.5
```

However, whenever I try to build `pgmagick` I get the following error:

```
/usr/include/boost/python/converter/registered.hpp: In instantiation of ‘const boost::python::converter::registration& boost::python::converter::detail::registered_base<const volatile void>::converters’:
/usr/include/boost/python/converter/arg_from_python.hpp:269:   instantiated from ‘boost::python::converter::pointer_arg_from_python<T>::pointer_arg_from_python(PyObject*) [with T = void*]’
/usr/include/boost/python/arg_from_python.hpp:70:   instantiated from ‘boost::python::arg_from_python<T>::arg_from_python(PyObject*) [with T = void*]’
/usr/include/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/local.hpp:37:   instantiated from ‘PyObject* boost::python::detail::caller_arity<3u>::impl<F, Policies, Sig>::operator()(PyObject*, PyObject*) [with F = void (*)(Magick::Blob&, void*, long unsigned int), Policies = boost::python::default_call_policies, Sig = boost::mpl::vector4<void, Magick::Blob&, void*, long unsigned int>]’
/usr/include/boost/python/object/py_function.hpp:38:   instantiated from ‘PyObject* boost::python::objects::caller_py_function_impl<Caller>::operator()(PyObject*, PyObject*) [with Caller = boost::python::detail::caller<void (*)(Magick::Blob&, void*, long unsigned int), boost::python::default_call_policies, boost::mpl::vector4<void, Magick::Blob&, void*, long unsigned int> >]’
./src/_Blob.cpp:43:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/boost/python/converter/registered.hpp:88: error: no matching function for call to ‘registry_lookup(const volatile void (*)())’
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I've also tried installing `boost141`, `boost141-devel` and `boost141-python` but pgmagick won't build against those libraries.

Any suggestions on how I can fix the problem, or further diagnose the issue?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but have you looked at the Python Imaging Library? http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/ Or at using the `subprocess` module to execute GraphicsMagick directly?

Comment: @RolandSmith unfortunately PIL doesn't have the features we require. Using `subprocess` is an option, but also it's quite a pain since the app has been developed using pgmagick directly - a lot of code would need to be reworked.

Comment: Look at how other distributions build packages for pgmagick. Maybe specific patches are needed? The pgmagick homepage mentions using `libboost-python1.40-dev` on Ubuntu.

Comment: what version of CentOS are you using? I just tried to build the extension on my Scientific Linux 6.2 (installed boost/graphics-magick dependencies from repo, downloaded source, did `python setup.py build`) and didn't have any issues there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the only way to get this working was to:

- remove all the pre-compiled `boost` rpms from the system
- remove all the pre-compiled `GraphicsMagick` rpms from the system
- compile `boost-1.49.0` manually, using `./configure --prefix=/usr --enable-shared=yes`
- reinstall `GraphicsMagick-1.3.14`, `GraphicsMagick-c++-1.3.14`, `GraphicsMagick-devel-1.3.14` and `GraphicsMagick-c++-devel-1.3.14` via `yum`
- clone the `pgmagick` repository from bitbucket
- run `python setup.py install` again within the `pgmagick` directory

Answer (score 1):

It looks like versions incompatibility problem, try using **boost-1.34**

Comment: CentOS doesn't seem to have boost-1.34 available. Would it be best to install this manually?

Comment: I'd just use some non-official repo like this one: http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/8359010/dir/centos_5/com/boost-1.34.1-11.1.x86_64.rpm.html

Comment: Generally I don't recommend installing packages from non-official repos.  You should only do that if you're willing to take the risks involved.

According to the pgmagick docs, boost141 and your GraphicsMagick libraries should be supported: http://packages.python.org/pgmagick/tutorial.html#requirements

Answer (score 1):

When you ran configure, I'm assuming you executed it as `./configure --enable-shared=yes` (note the parameter). If you did that (like the tutorial says), I see no reason why it shouldn't be working. If you didn't, this may help.